# How would I generate solutions to fill in a 3x3 matrix with the numbers 1-9 and all rows and columns adding up to 1 number?

Tags: python, math, matrix

I am trying to find a way to get as many solutions as possible for a 3x3 matrix to have all rows and columns add up to the same number. It must use the numbers 1-9. I figured out that I need to use 1 big, med, and small number in each row for it to work.
**Ex:**

```
2  4  9 = 15
6  8  1 = 15
7  3  5 = 15
=  =  =
15 15
```

I have a dict with the usable numbers grouped by size and a matrix with the 3 biggest numbers each of which are in a separate row because nothing would add up to them if they were in the same row.

```
nums = {
    "small" : [1, 2, 3],
    "med" : [4, 5, 6],
    "big" : [7, 8, 9]
}

m = [
    [0, 0, 9],
    [0, 8, 0],
    [7, 0, 0]
]
```

What would be the best way to find all possible solutions to this?

Comment: Do you want to know how generate all solutions or the "best" way? If it's the latter, what do you consider "best"? Regardless, I think there's probably a relatively small number of possible sums that would work, so you could speed things up by eliminating any combination that would exceed one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems to solve:

1. Generate new possible solutions
2. Verify that the solution is valid

Step one is easy; python includes a `permutation` function which will generate every single arrangement of numbers for you.  Then you need to verify that the sums all agree. We can simplify that by using [@JohanC's observation that each row and column must sum to 15](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59905277/596242).

```
from itertools import permutations


def all_sums():
    # Generate all possible grids
    r = range(1, 10)
    grids = permutations(r)

    # Only keep grids that are valid solutions
    solutions = [g for g in grids if _all_sums_are_15(g)]
    return solutions


def _all_sums_are_15(grid):
    """Check that each row and column of the grid sums to 15"""
    return (_sum_is_15(grid, 0, 1, 2) and
            _sum_is_15(grid, 3, 4, 5) and
            _sum_is_15(grid, 6, 7, 8) and
            _sum_is_15(grid, 0, 3, 6) and
            _sum_is_15(grid, 1, 4, 7) and
            _sum_is_15(grid, 2, 5, 8))


def _sum_is_15(grid, a, b, c):
    """Determine if the given 3 cells in the grid sum up to 15"""
    sum_ = grid[a] + grid[b] + grid[c]
    return sum_ == 15


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for s in all_sums():
        print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the sum of each row/column must necessarily be 15, because the sum of the 3 rows together must be equal to the sum of the numbers from 1 to 9, so 45.

Here is a way to generate all 72 solutions using [Z3](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm), an open source [SAT/SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) solver. Note that Z3 is a powerful solver for this kind of combinatorial problems, and probably a bit overkill for this specific one. But it can be used as an example of how such combinatorial problems can be handled, also much trickier ones. See e.g. [this](https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf) long list of examples.

```
from z3 import *

# get 9 integer variables for the matrix elements
M = [[Int(f"m{i}{j}") for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
# create a Z3 solver instance
s = Solver()
# all numbers must be between 1 and 9
s.add([And(M[i][j] >= 1, M[i][j] <= 9) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)])
# all the rows must sum to 15
s.add([And([Sum([M[i][j] for j in range(3)]) == 15]) for i in range(3)])
# all the columns must sum to 15
s.add([And([Sum([M[i][j] for i in range(3)]) == 15]) for j in range(3)])
# all 9 numbers must be distinct
s.add(Distinct([M[i][j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]))
res = s.check()
num_solutions = 0
while res == sat:
    num_solutions += 1
    m = s.model()
    print(num_solutions, ":", [[m[M[i][j]] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)])
    # add a new condition that at least one of the elements must be different to the current solution
    s.add(Or([m[M[i][j]].as_long() != M[i][j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]))
    res = s.check()
```

Output:

```
1 : [[3, 4, 8], [5, 9, 1], [7, 2, 6]]
2 : [[5, 7, 3], [9, 2, 4], [1, 6, 8]]
3 : [[6, 8, 1], [7, 3, 5], [2, 4, 9]]
...
72 : [[7, 5, 3], [6, 1, 8], [2, 9, 4]]
```

All solutions are equivalent to each other. You can permute rows and or columns of a solution to get another. And you can mirror a solution. 3! row permutations times 3! column permutations times 2 for the mirroring, 72 altogether.